# Which Would Be a Better Way to Code This CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser

My page has an H2 class that says

```
H2.clearboth {clear: both; height:16px;}
```

This works fine in I.E. but in Firefox and Chrome I need to ignore the `height` property because that is what is messing up the design. Is there a way for me to do this for Firefox and Chrome?

So I tried to do a browser specific `-moz` but there is no specific property for ignoring just `height`.

Thanks for any help or advice on this,

thanks,
Paul

Comment: Why are you adding a height to the h2?

Comment: I did not create the css file so I am trying to leave in there what it came with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could treat IE as exception, and in your html add:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
    H2.clearboth {height:16px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Then your css could be fine:

```
H2.clearboth {clear: both;}
```

Better yet, why do you use `H2{height:16px;}` only on IE and not on all browsers?

Comment: Not going to downvote here and while this solution will work, it feels a bit _hacky_. I don't feel conditional comments are required for this.

Comment: @hungerstar fell free to submit your better solution

Comment: What would be another solution you think other than what was suggested above?

Comment: Can you use conditional comments around the HTML tag like bootstrap? You could then do say, `.ie8 .h2.clearboth` ?

Comment: @PaulSquillace I would have to see more of the markup and page layout to know why you are using `clear: both;` and setting a `height` on the `h2`. Without that info I could suggest a number of things like using a `clearfix` on the content prior to the `h2` or using something else to set the`height` of the `h2`. That context is not provided in the question so an answer is not forthcoming just yet.

Comment: IE is the one that works in this situation, as hard as it is to believe. It is FF and Chrome where the copy context is crashing or overlaying each other.